# Rollup with absolute Typescript imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, rollup

- Source: here: https://github.com/arvigeus/roll-on-slow
- Output bundle: [dist](https://github.com/arvigeus/roll-on-slow/tree/master/dist)
- Build log: [build.log](https://github.com/arvigeus/roll-on-slow/blob/master/build.log)

Rollup bundles it fine, but it throws some warnings for wrong source maps (`Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.`). The root of the problem seems to be `@babel/preset-react` [`development: true`](https://github.com/arvigeus/roll-on-slow/blob/master/babel.config.js#L15) (setting it `false` makes the warning disappear). Am I doing something wrong, or this is expected behavior? The generated code seems fine to me...

There is also a warning about `'this' has been rewritten to 'undefined'`, seems related because it disappears when switching off that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I decided to disable `development: true` and set it to `false`. Definitely it should not be true when building libraries.